# Input-Type Submit Behind Div Element

Tags: html, input, form-submit

I have used input-type submit, but now I would like to change it to  the button style. To this end, I have used the code below:

```
<div class="cartbutton">
     <input type="submit" name="shortname" value="product1" class="add_to_cart" />
     <div class="buttoninner">
          <div class="buttontext">Add to Cart</div><div class="cartimage"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have positioned the `buttoninner` div element above the input-type submit using the CSS below:

```
.cartbutton {
    position: relative;
    width: 178px;
}

.add_to_cart {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 38px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 177px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.buttontext {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: 0 none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
.cartimage {
    background-color: #F7941D;
    background-image: url("/Content/en-US/Sales/Images/small_cart.png");
    background-position: 5px 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 38px;
    width: 40px;
}
.buttoninner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, the button post not working. How can I active the submit button behind the div element?

Answer (score 1):

```
 why are you using div you can use 
 <input type="image" src="image path">
  it also works like submit
```

Comment: div because i want to use text with image. if we click on both image and text, form submit need to trigger

Comment: see my another answer with click event it will help u

Comment: previously i have used button tag inside that placed div elements. It was working fine in all browser except IE7. But IE7 not supported button tag so only i have used input type submit and positioned div element over it.Now i hate to do click event because all browser support normal button post except IE 7.

Comment: so use the above case of image type of input and through css add or control your text that u want to add

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="cartbutton" >
 <input type="submit" name="shortname" value="product1" class="add_to_cart" />
 <div class="buttoninner">
 <div class="buttontext">Add to Cart</div><div class="cartimage"></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('.cartbutton').click(function(){
 $('#formid').submit();
  });
  </script>
 use jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

well the reasons seems because your button is not actually clicked as you have overlayed div over it. What you can do is just give your div an onclick event and handle the submit action through it. you will not need a separate submit button in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button anywhere in php echo or print it. Css class can be modified as per requirement.

```
print "<div class='links' id='edit-submit'><input type='button' class='form-submit' value='Signup to Invitation' onClick=\"location.href='?q=rsvp/".$rsvp->rid."/register';\" \></div>";
```